# Does IIS worker process crash on high CPU or RAM?

Tags: iis, application-pool, worker-process

I would like to know what happens to the worker process when the server runs at full capacity.

Im asking because sometimes my web application loads very slow and throw me server error (without any code).

Comment: Do you know which of your resources is maxed-out?  CPU, HDD, network, RAM, DB?

Comment: Its the RAM but it could also be the CPU. Even if they reach the max capacity I should not see any server error or should I?

Comment: Max for RAM is more likely to cause a crash. Especially if you have a memory leak.  Then the IIS process will restart the application pool for your app.  If you are max for CPU, the app will just be slow sometimes, and not crash.  However, you could experience timeouts, which might throw errors (depends on logic in the program. Most programmers don't think to handle timeouts gracefully).  Same for maxed-out bandwidth: slowness, timeouts, unhandled errors.

Comment: If you are not sure which is the culprit, please use TaskMan or PerfMon to get some graphs of your server.  The treatment and side-effects for each is different. Don't guess, because you will probably end-up treating the wrong-one. Which is unproductive.